# PayPal.initWithAppID() crashes with NullPointerException

Tags: android, paypal, crash, nullpointerexception, unity-game-engine

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5195
 java.lang.NullPointerException: src == null
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.paypal.android.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.paypal.android.a.h.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal.setLanguage(Unknown Source)
    at com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal.initWithAppID(Unknown Source)
    at com.lonfun.pets.UnityPayMenuActivity.initLibrary(UnityPayMenuActivity.java:256)
    at com.lonfun.pets.UnityPayMenuActivity.access$2(UnityPayMenuActivity.java:249)
    at com.lonfun.pets.UnityPayMenuActivity$2$1.run(UnityPayMenuActivity.java:175)
```

I just use android to open paypal, everything is ok, but if I call from unity, this is happened!
this is my java code:

package com.paypal.androidpets;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;

import com.lonfun.pets.UnityPayMenuActivity;
import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal;
import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity;

public class PaypalTool {
    Context context;
    PayPal pp;
    private static final int server = PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX;
    // The ID of your application that you received from PayPal
    private static final String appID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";

    public PaypalTool(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void initLibrary(final Handler handler) 
    {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                PayPalActivity._paypal = null;
                pp = PayPal.getInstance();
                // If the library is already initialized, then we don't need to initialize it again.
                if(pp == null) {
//                  pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(context, "", PayPal.ENV_NONE);
                    pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(context, appID, server);

                    pp.setShippingEnabled(false);
                }

                if (PayPal.getInstance().isLibraryInitialized()) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
                else {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

has anybody solve this problem,,please help me, thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PayMoneyHandler : MonoBehaviour
{

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    static AndroidJavaClass payPluginClass;
    static AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer;
    static AndroidJavaObject currActivity;
    #endif

    public static void Pay(string productID)
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        jo.Call("StartActivity0", 
            "com.peten.tier2", 
            "EGAHCNJDEJBWBIBWEXIKDEGLJECOAD.Mac", 
            "Dog", 
            "AndDogCn", 
            "http://42.121.94.123/TradeWeb/AlipayTrade.aspx",
            "http://58.246.188.238/TradeWeb/PaypalTrade.aspx"
            );
#endif
    }

}
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestForPaypal : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void OnClick(){
        Debug.Log("Test For Paypal!");
        PayMoneyHandler.Pay("test1");
    }
}

public void StartActivity0(final String name,final String PlayerName,final String GameID,final String ZoneID,final String payUrl,final String paypalUrl) 
    {       
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("Order", "name:"+name+"PlayerName:"+PlayerName+"GameID:"+GameID+"ZoneID:"+ZoneID+"payUrl:"+payUrl+"paypalUrl:"+paypalUrl);
                Intent payintent=new Intent(mContext,UnityPayMenuActivity.class);
                payintent.putExtra("name",name);
                payintent.putExtra("PlayerName",PlayerName);
                payintent.putExtra("GameID",GameID);
                payintent.putExtra("ZoneID",ZoneID);
                payintent.putExtra("payUrl",payUrl);
                payintent.putExtra("paypalUrl",paypalUrl);
                Unity3DMainActiviy.this.startActivity(payintent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you please upload the full code of piece of code ?

Comment: private static final int server = PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX;
 // The ID of your application that you received from PayPal
private static final String appID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";  I defined  before,

Comment: i add full code, if I write a android app used paypal, it works well, but call PaypalTool from Unity3D ，then crash allways,

Comment: fine, can you upload Unity's code as well ?

Comment: StartActivity0 method is unity3D call android paypal, i call alipay work well,

Comment: opps, that's out of syllabus for me :P

Comment: I am pretty sure c# code is right, I can call google checkout, so...

Comment: I have no idea, have to write a android Paypal apk into myGame.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnot enter the appID and the server detail.
Below is the working code which i have implement and It works fine for me.
I have implement Pay on button click which extends the runnable

```
 Check_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if (_paypalLibraryInit) {
         showPayPalButton();
         //Toast.makeText(Android_PP_Test1Activity.this, captions[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
             else {
             // Display a progress dialog to the user and start checking for when
         // the initialization is completed


             Thread initThread = new Thread(initLibraryRunnable);
             initThread.start();

             _progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Recharge.this);
         _progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
         _progressDialog.setMessage("Loading PayPal Payment Library");
         _progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
         _progressDialog.show();
         _progressDialogRunning = true;
         Thread newThread = new Thread(checkforPayPalInitRunnable);

         newThread.start();
         //Toast.makeText(Android_PP_Test1Activity.this, "Picasso Paintings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }


});
```

This button call this runnable method

```
//This lets us run the initLibrary function
    final Runnable initLibraryRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            initLibrary();
        }
    };
```

and this method is responsible to initiate the initLibrary.

```
 /** init method **/
public void initLibrary() {
    PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
    if (pp == null) {
        // This is the main initialization call that takes in your Context,
        // the Application ID, and the server you would like to connect to.
        pp=PayPal.initWithAppID(this,"APP80W284485P519543T",PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

        // -- These are required settings.
        pp.setLanguage("en_US"); // Sets the language for the library.
        // --

        // -- These are a few of the optional settings.
        // Sets the fees payer. If there are fees for the transaction, this
        // person will pay for them. Possible values are FEEPAYER_SENDER,
        // FEEPAYER_PRIMARYRECEIVER, FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER, and
        // FEEPAYER_SECONDARYONLY.
        pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);
        // Set to true if the transaction will require shipping.
        pp.setShippingEnabled(true);
        // Dynamic Amount Calculation allows you to set tax and shipping
        // amounts based on the user's shipping address. Shipping must be
        // enabled for Dynamic Amount Calculation. This also requires you to
        // create a class that implements PaymentAdjuster and Serializable.
        pp.setDynamicAmountCalculationEnabled(false);
        // -- 


    }
}
```

Hope It helps...

Comment: If you need further more assistance paypal also provide the documentation for this
[Paypal MPL integration in Android](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/how-to-guides/how-accept-payments-android-app-using-mpl)

Comment: private static final int server = PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX;
 // The ID of your application that you received from PayPal
 private static final String appID = "APP-80W284485P519543T"; I defined before

Comment: I am pretty sure, i use this code just android it works well, no problem, but it call from unity3D，then nullpoint. I can call google checkout from Unity3D, but call paypal, crash!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when unity generates the apk file. I have compared one apk i made miself with PayPal integration only compiling with eclipse and other compiling with Unity.

Lets say the apk i made only with eclipse is called "PayPalOnlyEclipse.apk" and the one made with unity "PayPalWithUnity.apk"; y renamed them to "PayPalOnlyEclipse.zip" and "PayPalWithUnity.zip", then open both with WinRar to compare them.

I found that PayPalOnlyEclipse had one folder that PayPalWithUnity didn't, the folder is "com\paypal\android\utils\data". So I decompressed that folder and then added it to PayPalWithUnity. Then erase the META-INF folder (the signing), then close the "PayPalWithUnity.zip" and rename it like it was before ("PayPalWithUnity.apk").

Then I used the command for signing the apk file:
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my.keystore PayPalWithUnity.apk user

Finally I used the command for zipalign:
zipalign -v 4 PayPalWithUnity.apk PayPalWithUnity2.apk

that command generates PayPalWithUnity2.apk and that is the apk file you have to install in your phone.

Hope it helps, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have included the PaypalActivity on manifest file. Like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

If you have it and it doesnt work yet, include the library on the build path (Properties>>Java Buid Path>>Libraries>>Add JARs) and add it on the "order and export" tab (Properties>>Java Buid Path>>Order and Export).